# Do docker images have access to the tmp dir?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to understand to what extent a docker image has access to a /tmp/ directory.

In my case I'm using the frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim image and my app needs to write to a temp folder.

When i define tmpfs like this in my docker-compose (v2) file:

`df_server:
    image: "${DF_IMAGE}"
    build: .
    tmpfs:
      - /tmp`

I get an error saying that the directory exists already. When I try to access the directory from my webapp, I get an error saying the directory does not exist.

When I define the tmpfs dir as anything else, e.g.

    `tmpfs:
      - /foobar`

My webapp can access and use the the directory foobar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most images based on a distro will come with a `/tmp` directory inside the image. This will use whatever storage driver Docker is set to use.

```
$ docker run -ti frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim ls -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt    2 root     root          4096 Oct 18 18:58 /tmp
```

Which can be written to

```
$ docker run -ti frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim \
    time dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero bs=4k count=64k
32768+0 records in
32768+0 records out
real    0m 0.84s
user    0m 0.00s
sys     0m 0.11s
```

Mounting tmpfs adds an in memory /tmp instead

```
$ docker run -ti --tmpfs /tmp frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim \
    time dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/zero bs=4k count=64k
65536+0 records in
65536+0 records out
real    0m 0.13s
user    0m 0.01s
sys     0m 0.12s
```

And you should be able to write and read from it (different alpine based image)

```
docker run -ti --tmpfs /tmp mhart/alpine-node node -e '
  fs.writeFile(`/tmp/test`, `test`, (err, res) => {
    console.log(`write`, err, res)
    fs.readFile(`/tmp/test`, (err, data) => console.log(`read`, err, data))
  })'

null undefined
null <Buffer 74 65 73 74>
```

I'm not sure how you are getting a "directory exists already" error.

Maybe try the same on a different Docker host? Pull the latest `frolvlad/alpine-oraclejdk8:slim`?